# MTU affects access to some sites

Tags: mtu

I'm no expert in this field, so I thought I would come on here and get some opinions.  I have issues accessing certain websites, one example is codility.com.  As I understand it (and correct me if I am wrong) 1500 is a pretty standard MTU setting?  However, on the sites I have issues accessing this gives me massive packet loss i.e.:

```
ping -s 1464 -c1 codility.com
PING codility.com (52.71.87.144) 1464(1492) bytes of data.

--- codility.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

But the same thing on say Google, works every time:

```
ping -s 1464 -c1 google.com
PING google.com (216.58.213.174) 1464(1492) bytes of data.
72 bytes from lhr26s02-in-f174.1e100.net (216.58.213.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 (truncated)

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.234/25.234/25.234/0.000 ms
```

I have to bring MTU down to around 1200 in order to not drop packets on Codility:

```
ping -s 1172 -c1 codility.com
PING codility.com (52.71.87.144) 1172(1200) bytes of data.
1180 bytes from ec2-52-71-87-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com (52.71.87.144): icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=119 ms

--- codility.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 119.048/119.048/119.048/0.000 ms
```

In fact, the exact highest value seems to be 1204:

```
ping -s 1176 -c1 codility.com
PING codility.com (52.71.87.144) 1176(1204) bytes of data.
1184 bytes from ec2-52-71-87-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com (52.71.87.144): icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=123 ms

--- codility.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 123.843/123.843/123.843/0.000 ms
```

From 1205 or higher, I get complete packet loss:

```
ping -s 1177 -c1 codility.com
PING codility.com (52.71.87.144) 1177(1205) bytes of data.

--- codility.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Can anyone give me a bit of general advice and information here?  Is this normal?  Should I set my MTU permanently to 1200?  What affect will this have?  From what I have looked at the router I use I believe has an MTU of 1500 so am I looking at ISP issue here?

Comment: What is the router model?

Comment: It's a BT Home Hub 3.0B.

Comment: You didn't read the [help/on-topic], or you ignored it. "_(Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly OFF-topic.)_"

Comment: Ah right apologies, I didn't read that first.  Feel free to remove the question, I'll find a more suitable place to ask it.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this with a similar issue, it's looking like in my case the problem was actually down to a powerline adapter - looks like it didn't support the full packet size.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: the 1500 packet size is for the whole packet. With several layers of protocol headers and other overhead there is less than 1500 bytes for the payload. The "-s" option of ping sets the size of the payload, not of the packet.

For the other half:

Somewhere between your host and your target there seems to be a line with a smaller MTU. The router at that line has two options:

splitting the packet into smaller fragments that will fit into that MTU (which most routers won't do because it's more work for them)

or

drop the packet and send back a message to the source ip saying "packet dropped, send smaller packages. I can fit up to 1200 bytes through the line". The sender can then send smaller packets.

The latter will be an ICMP packet. Malconfigured firewalls might drop the ICMP-packet (because some people think that ICMP is "only used by hackers") so the sender never knows what happened to the packet.

This process is called PMTU Discovery and it needs ICMP to function.

Comment: Right ok, so if I am correct in my thinking when you say "Somewhere between your host and your target there seems to be a line with a smaller MTU", this suggests to me it's an issue possibly more related to the site I am browsing (or at least at some point on the route which is specific to that site) as it doesn't happen on other sites?

Comment: Yeah, but don't think it's uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely do not set your MTU to 1200 - this will cause you performance issues elsewhere.

Can you provide more information on your topology?  Is it just your PC and a router, or is this a corporate environment where there is a bigger network between you and the Internet?

When you are testing for supported MTU you'll need to use one of the following commands to ensure that the Do-Not-Fragment bit is set in the ICMP request:

- Linux: `ping -s 1480 -M do codility.com`
- Mac OS X: `ping -s 1480 -D codility.com`
- Windows: `ping -l 1480 -f codility.com`

otherwise ping will happily report that it received back a packet of any size (even though it may have been fragmented into smaller frames in order to be received).  eg:

```
 bdale@lojack:~$ ping -s 5000 codility.com
 PING codility.com (52.71.87.144) 5000(5028) bytes of data.
 5008 bytes from ec2-52-71-87-144.compute-1.amazonaws.com (52.71.87.144): icmp_req=1 ttl=38 time=242 ms
```

(no, I don't have interfaces capable of 5000 byte frames all the way between myself and AWS!)

Try to isolate the issue a bit further - is it a problem between you and AWS (where codility is hosted)? - Try the same ping test on 52.71.87.150 (live host in the same AWS subnet) and see if you get the same results.

Run a traceroute between yourself and both these addresses and then to another site hosted on AWS (prlog.com) - does your traffic follow the same path?

Does your network connect directly to AWS already via a VPN?  You may be routing all AWS addresses over this tunnel which would give a reduced MTU (but more like 1350 bytes as opposed to 1200).  If this is the case, you will need to adjust tcp-mss settings on your router so that TCP traffic passing over this tunnel is clamped down below 1200 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try those things.  Yes the setup is just a simple PC -> router -> internet.